# How to iterate through a bootstrap card with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm not sure where put the start and end of my iteration

Im using bootstrap frame work and its supposed to look like this

[what bootstrap looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiSjD.png)

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3">
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is what mine looks like

[what mine loos like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59D7a.png)

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3">
  <% @apparels.each do |apparel| %>
      <div class="col mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <%= image_tag apparel.picture, class: 'card-img-top', width: 300 if apparel.picture.attached?%>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"> <%= apparel.brand %> <%= apparel.model %></h5>
            <p class="card-text">Size: <%= apparel.size %><br>$<%= apparel.price %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<% end %>
  </div>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want each 3 boxes per-row, you can change line 3 to col-md-4, total each column is 12, so 12/4 = 3 it will automatically moving to next row

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3">
  <% @apparels.each do |apparel| %>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <%= image_tag apparel.picture, class: 'card-img-top', width: 300 if apparel.picture.attached?%>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"> <%= apparel.brand %> <%= apparel.model %></h5>
            <p class="card-text">Size: <%= apparel.size %><br>$<%= apparel.price %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```